# No echo for form data using GET method in PHP

Tags: php, html

Fairly new to PHP. Have been trying a simple program to get data from 2 fields and display it using GET method.

Heres the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Form</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <form action="send.php" method="get" id="sample">
        Name:<input type="text" name="user"/>
        Message:<input type="text" name="message"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the PHP code:

```
<html>
<body>
  Welcome <?php echo $_GET["user"]; ?>
  Message <?php echo $_GET["message"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The GET method fetches the data as a QueryString in address bar of browser, but doesn't display anything in browser window.

Comment: Have your got any error???

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to check error in page

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); in your code

Comment: What is your second file extension? is it .php or .html ?

Comment: send.php has get variable right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works perfectly. Reinstalling WAMP server solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to start the server. 
Go to your directory where the index.html file of your website lives,  then run the command line php -S localhost:5000. 
 5000 is the port where php is listening to, you can put any value there.... 
Install php if you haven't.. Or Wamp

Comment: Why the down vote?  Judging from your question your new and looking for answers go read the documentation before posting it here.